# How to return a custom message instead of an empty array from a Mongoose Find query when no results are found

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose

I'm trying to  return a custom message when I do a `mongoose.find` query and it doesn't find anything on the system.

At the moment I have the following and it works, but I was wondering if there is a better way of accomplishing what I'm doing .

```js
// <status> => one of ["valid", "expired", "attributed"]

const getByStatus = (status) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    PhotoCodes.find({ status: status })
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}
```

```js
router.post('/byStatus', (req, res, next) => {
  const { status } = req.body

  photoCodesModel
    .getByStatus(status)
    .then((response) => {    
      if (response.length == 0 ) {
        res.status(404).send('Not Found') // [ASK]: If response is an empty "[]" treat it as nothing was found. Is there a better way of doing this?
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok', data: response })
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({ result: 'ok', error: error })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await to do, like this

```
const getByStatus = async (status) => {
    const photo =   await PhotoCodes.find({ status: status })
    return photo   .
  }

router.post('/byStatus',async (req, res, next) => {
  const status = req.body.status;
  try {
  const photo = await getByStatus(status)
  if(photo.length!==0) {
    return res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok', data: photo })
  }
    return res.status(404).json({message : "treat it as nothing was found"})
  }
  catch(error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ result: 'ok', error: error })
  }
});
```